# spring cloud stream kafka binder resetting a kafka topic(multiple partitions) offset to an arbitrary number programatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a requirement to reset offset to a number.

**Detailed requirement** : My application is consuming messages from kafka topic and dumping it in DB, let's say DB goes down while processing the consumed messages(offset=10) and till the time DB was down the application consumed messages till offset 20.

Now DB comes up again while processing the 20th offset message, now I want to reset the offset to 10 again so that I can save the data in database.

Can I achieve that programatically (spring boot) ?
I am using spring cloud stream binder kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Why continue to receive messages if the DB is down?

Simply configure the listener container to keep retrying the current record until the DB is available again.

```java
@Bean
ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> listenerContainerCustomizer() {
    return (container, topic, group) -> {
        container.setErrorHandler(...);
    };
}
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek-to-current

Comment: Hi Gary..Thanks for the answer, I have to continue receiving message because per message we do some calculation and push the calculated values to downstream systems/topics and that value should be latest. I can't wait for DB to come UP, it can work without DB, but  those consumed message should be present in DB for some other requirement. So that's why when DB comes up I want to reset the offset to arbitrary number(offset value when DB went down), somehow I am keeping track of offset values. So how can I do that?? I saw 'consumer.seek()' method works around it???

Comment: SCSt does not provide an API for arbitrary seeks at runtime. Calling seek directly on the consumer will cause problems with sequencing and offset committing. One solution would be to write a custom error handler and throw an exception that contains information about which partitions need seeks, and to where (as well as any other remaining partitions from the last poll). This is not trivial code.  How much are you relying on Spring Cloud Stream? If you use Spring for Apache Kafka directly instead, you can perform seeks.

Comment: Another option, perhaps simpler, might be to use manual acks for offset commits and stop acknowledging while the DB is down; when it comes back up stop and restart the binding and consumption will begin at the point you stopped acking records.

Comment: Thanks Gary, will try these approach